Azure Devops, How to extract latest tag present in a repository using Rest APIs?
I'm trying to fetch latest tag of a Azure git repo using Rest API.
So first fetched all tags of a repo using rest api.
But this json returned the tags in no fixed order i.e sometimes latest tag is at top and sometimes at bottom.
Due to this I'm not able to extract.
I tried below snippet in bash, but it returned random tag, not latest.
tags_response=$(curl -s -u ":$pat" \
"https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo_id/refs?filter=tags&api-version=7.1-preview.1")

# Extract the latest tag
latest_tag=$(echo $tags_response | jq -r '.value | sort_by(.name) | last(.[]).name')


TL;DR it's possible to get the creation date of an annotated tag, but not of a  lightweight tag (see Use Git tags).
Use the Annotated Tags - Get endpoint to get the metadata (including the creation date) of a specific tag.
Sample response:
{
  "name": "refs/tags/v0.1-beta2",
  "objectId": "69080710948ac8ba63e44eca2daf0b30f38c428d",
  "taggedObject": {
    "objectId": "c60be62ebf0e86b5aa01dbb98657b4b7e5905234",
    "objectType": "commit"
  },
  "taggedBy": {
    "name": "Norman Paulk",
    "email": "Fabrikamfiber16@hotmail.com",
    "date": "2017-06-22T04:28:23"
  },
  "message": "First beta release",
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/ca93c3a5-87bb-4b5b-a62f-1f971d677c79/annotatedTags/69080710948ac8ba63e44eca2daf0b30f38c428d"
}

More details
Azure DevOps supports both annotated and lightweight tags:

Lightweight tags are a pointer to specific commit
Annotated tags contain more information such as the tagger, message, and date

You can create annotated tags using the web portal. You can create both lightweight and annotated tags from within Visual Studio.
Seeing the details of a tag created in the web portal:


@RuiJarmiba Thanks a lot. It worked. First I extracted all tags using repository rest APIs and then used the objectId returned by this json to extract creation time of tag using annotated tag rest API.

@cris7ronaldo great! Don't forget to upvote and/or accept my answer :-)

haha, sure. But stackoverflow not allowing me to upvote, saying "you need at least 15 reputations". I'm new to this platform, so am not sure how to increase the reputations.

@cris7ronaldo try now. Reputation is increased when people upvote your questions/answers, and accept your answers. PS: You probably don't need 15 reputation to accept answers.
